# Migrate OSGI application from Karaf 2.3.4 to Websphere Application server

Tags: websphere, osgi, karaf

I have an OSGI application deployed in Karaf v2.3.4, it worked well, but I want to migrate it to WebSphere application server, I want to know the difference between these two servers, and the guidlines for doing that

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I've lead the development of OSGi applications on WebSphere, but am less familiar with Karaf. From what I can tell, we share the same Blueprint implementation. I believe that Karaf supports the OSGi application (.eba) packaging model - WebSphere Application Server insists upon it.

You can download free, developer-licensed WebSphere Application Server runtimes and Eclipse-based tooling from wasdev.net. The simplest approach would be to import your application source into the tooling, and deploy it onto a runtime from there.

The Karaf home page describes it as 'a small OSGi based runtime which provides a lightweight container onto which various components and applications can be deployed.' WebSphere Application Server is a Java EE-compliant application server. Until the advent of the Liberty Profile, it could not have been described as 'small'. Both runtimes are OSGi based.

We don't have a specific guide for migrating OSGi applications from Karaf to WebSphere, which is why I recommend that you try it and see what happens. Good luck - do let us know how you get on, either here or on the wasdev.net forums.

Regards, 
Mark